# touch events not working on programatically created view

Tags: ios

I want to create the view with button, textbox, label programatically in viewdidload
But touch events are not working on view and its subviews even though i have set userinteractionenabled to YES.
Here is my code:

```
    CGRect bounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

    //creating a view
    UIView* mainView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: bounds];
    [mainView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [mainView setBackgroundColor: [UIColor yellowColor]];    
    CGRect buttonFrame = CGRectMake( 100, 80, 100, 50 );
    UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    myButton.frame = buttonFrame;
    [myButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    myButton.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    [myButton addTarget: self
               action: @selector(buttonClicked:)
     forControlEvents: UIControlEventAllTouchEvents];    
    [myButton setTitle: @"My Button" forState: UIControlStateNormal];

 //adding button to myview

    [mainView addSubview: myButton];

    //adding label to myview

    UILabel* myLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 100)];
    myLabel.text=@"my text";
    [mainView addSubview:myLabel];

    //adding textbox to myview   

    UITextField* textbox=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 210, 200, 50)];
    textbox.text=@"my text in textfield";
    textbox.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    [mainView addSubview:textbox];    

    //finally adding my view to self.view

    [self.view addSubview:mainView];
```

Comment: did you make sure that your buttonClicked method is called ?

Comment: This exact code is working for me, can you show your buttonClicked: method ?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
//creating a view
UIView* mainView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: bounds];
[mainView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[mainView setBackgroundColor: [UIColor yellowColor]];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tappedOnView:)]; //add the gesture to get the touch event
tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[mainView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

CGRect buttonFrame = CGRectMake( 100, 80, 100, 50 );
UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
myButton.frame = buttonFrame;
[myButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
myButton.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
[myButton addTarget: self
             action: @selector(buttonClicked:)
   forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[myButton setTitle: @"My Button" forState: UIControlStateNormal];

//adding button to myview

[mainView addSubview: myButton];

//adding label to myview

UILabel* myLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 100)];
myLabel.text=@"my text";
[mainView addSubview:myLabel];

//adding textbox to myview

UITextField* textbox=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 210, 200, 50)];
textbox.text=@"my text in textfield";
textbox.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
[mainView addSubview:textbox];

//finally adding my view to self.view

[self.view addSubview:mainView];
```

Answer (score 0):

modify the line

```
//UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
```

to

```
UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

and add the method in your code

```
-(void)buttonClicked:(UIButton *)button
{  
    NSLog(@"hai");

}
```

and select the checkbox `enable user interaction` in interface builder its working fine.